# what do you call a table that contains counts of items which have 2 characteristic attributes represented by the rows and columns?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, mathematics, technical, statistics

What do we call a table that holds counts? A binning table? Frequency table? Unnormalized probability density table?

What if, instead of a table, it's just a list? And what if the table has more than two dimensions?

Comment: Would you be able to add a small sample to demonstrate exactly the sort of table you mean?

Comment: http://education-portal.com/cimages/multimages/16/con2.jpg

Comment: This? http://img.youtube.com/vi/xpqcUsEZenk/0.jpg  source: http://imgarcade.com/1/frequency-table-definition/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for a technical term namely

> [Contingency table](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table)

or

> cross tab

which is a table of counts of items described by the row and column labels.